# Is there any harm in adding more dependencies in angular js controller or service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Suppose this is my angular controller

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $modal, $state,) {
});
```

I am thinking of having one global variable holding most commonly used dependencies like

`var all = ['$scope', '$modal', '$state']`

and then use `all` at every place  along with some other dependencies if needed

Is there any performace issue having put all dependencies everywhere

Comment: Attention: it will break after you minify your code.

Comment: @zerkms actually that was just example to show, i will use the proper way in code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having to inject more code would have a performance hit, but not a major one. I don't recommend defining your dependencies globally like that because dependencies should be very visible. You should know exactly what you're doing with them without having to open another file and check.

If you need to reuse a set of dependencies everywhere, that suggests more that there's probably something wrong with the code. How come different regions of the code base all talk to the same stuff? That suggests duplication of concerns. I don't extend that assertion to just having to inject $scope or $http all the time.

In short, I don't think it's a good idea to manage dependencies like that.

Comment: I agree here, dependencies should be explicitly stated for each component that requires it. Having such global dependency list has problem with unit testing too. You now have to mock many dependencies or pass nulls around..

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have deep knowledge of the Angular internals, nor have I bothered to actually measure the performance of what you are asking, I would venture my educated guess as .... no.  You're not going to see a performance impact here.  The only impact would be on controller instantiation, which only happens once per view.  And even then, we're just talking about new-ing up a few objects ... the perf impact ought to be very negligible, and not something I would worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject using a variable you define within another controller or service. One thing you could do is create a factory and put your dependencies in the $rootScope.

```
app.factory('root',function($rootScope, $modal, $state){
$rootScope.modal = $modal;
$rootScope.state = $state;
});
```

You just put $rootScope in all your controllers and you have access to whatever you like. You would only need to inject 'root' in your main controller (if you have one). It seems like fishy architecture to need this shortcut, but that is how I would do it. No perf hit really - non-primitives are reference types.

Comment: No need to polute `$rootScope`, just return an object from the factory..can even make the keys the same as the dependncies...inject `root` where needed

Comment: Yeah, should be a factory named all that returns the array. Dumb answer on my part.